# Hosting Oracle DB and Data Ware House functions virtually

Tags: database, oracle, hyper-v

I am trying to create a test environment (for my own practice and research) on how best to virtualize an Oracle DB using windows (Unix/Linux comes later...much later).

Here's the idea:

Use Virtual PC (for win7) and install Server 2008 x64 with Hyper V.  Then, create a virtual guest (XP or something) that connects to it.  Install an Oracle instance (11gR2) on the server and then go to work to connect to the DB instance from furhter vitualized XP O/S.
After that, create a Data Warehouse (DWH) on another virtualized O/S using the server as the data source.
Basically:
Server(DB) to DWH
Server(DB) to client computer
client computer (DWH Manager) to DWH

I would just like to know if this seems a valid way to build a testing environment or is this not such a good idea and there are better ways to do this?

Additionally, I am largely unfamiliar with Hyper-V Server 2008  and virtualization (even after reading the docs on it - someone with practical experience would be helpful in suggestions)

I have Win 7 x64 installed on my machine and have been running an 11gR2 DB for the past 6 months as part of a personal project (and continued education)

I appreciate any and all suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are your concerns?  The main disadvantage will be performance, but that's usually not that important in a development environment.

Comment: Mainly...(before I waste hours installing and updating the virutal server) is it possible and what type of server config do I need (apart from the hyper-v update)